# Calling a custom fragment from an activity

Tags: java, android-fragments

I creating my own Fragment that I wanna activate from my activity. My mainActivity file is a pure Activity (not a FragmantActivity or anything else). Why I can't use my custom Fragment as a parameter?

```
if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        // Add the fragment on initial activity setup
        myFragment = new CustomFragment();
        getFragmentManager()
        .beginTransaction()
                .add(android.R.id.content, myFragment )
                .commit();
```

I am getting a compile error telling me that the 2nd parameter on .add() method must be a Fragment, but 'myFragment' is a CustomFragment that derives Fragment class. So how to activate this fragment from a normal Activity?

Comment: make sure that CustomFragment inherits from 'android.app' not from 'android.support.v4.app'

Comment: My customFragment must be 'android.support.v4.app.Fragment' because I am using Facebook auth inside of it.

Comment: then use getSupportFragmentManager() instead of getFragmentManager()

Comment: This method can NOT be called from a normal activity, but from a fragmentActivity...

Comment: mine is working file even when activity inherits from AppCompatActivity

getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(android.R.id.content, new MyFragment()).commit();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that you're consistent with your Fragment imports. Use either import android.app.Fragment in all classes or  import android.support.v4.app.Fragment; in all classes. Don't mix-and-match

FragmentActivity or any child class of FragmentActivity only can hold the fragment from the support library. Hence change your activity's parent class to FragmentActivity, it will work. As AppCompatActivity inherits from FragmentActivity it also will work.